# Hex to TCP Port - BASH

Tags: linux, bash, tcp

so i have been working a lot with sending hex to a tcp port. Now, my next task is to do the following , BUT this is a different way of hex?

I guess i need some help because the documentation anywhere is really bad.

So far the hex i am told (the command) is like so

```
 01 53 20 00 41 04 4F
```

so normally, i would do the following in linux

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/IP OF SERVER/PORT TO SERVER
```

then

```
echo -ne '01 53 20 00 41 04 4F' >&3
```

then

```
echo <&3
```

but i get no reply back just blank.

Sorry i forgot to mention,

what i am use to doing is

echo -ne 54686973776f726b7366696e65 | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' >&3

and then 
echo <&3
and ill get a reply.

So my question is, what is the diff between 01 53 20 etc ..

I am a bit confused.

Comment: @robmayoff Sorry about that typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
echo -ne 54686973776f726b7366696e65 | perl -pe 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/chr hex $1/gie' >&3
```

you're piping your hex codes through Perl, which is breaking them up and translating them into 8-bit character codes for you.

Bash, on the other hand, doesn't handle text as well as Perl does (which is why you needed Perl in the first place).  At best, because you're not doing any translation whatsoever, the other side will see the literal text `01 53 20 00 41 04 4F`.

In order to do this entirely in Bash, you'd have to do something like

```
echo -ne '\x01\x53\x20\x00\x41\x04\x4f' >&3
```

The `\x##` codes are basically the equivalent of what Perl was doing with each pair of digits...and `-e` enables that translation.

For reference, this works just fine for me:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/80
# 'GET /\r\n'
echo '\x47\x45\x54\x20\x2f\x0d\x0a' >&3
# Note: `echo <&3` didn't work here, in my tests.
cat <&3
```

Comment: @user3100345: Try using `cat` instead of `echo`.  :P  I just tried with `cat`, and it works great.  `echo` didn't give me anything, which is no surprise to me -- it doesn't normally deal with input.

Comment: now that worked. Wow why would that work and not echo but echo works on all other commands i tried using a different hex scheme.

Comment: I dunno.  I'm actually semi surprised `echo` ever worked for you, as it doesn't read input.  If you were to try `echo 'stuff' | echo`, it should fail as well (giving you nothing but a blank line).

Comment: for my last question, maybe i can open another question but dont want to waste it.. how can i calculate the last bit of this which is the lower 8 bits of 01 53 20 00 41 04  of the result calculated in bytes  .. so basically 01 + 53 + etc. would equal my last part of that. which is 4F BUT how was that calculated? btw, the 01 53 20 00 41 04 are not the real hex codes i changed them for this post. thanks! @cHao

Comment: You're going to need to rephrase that in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry about that. So basically, 01 53 20 00 41 04 , then theres the last part of that which is 4F. IF i had the original Hex values here, they would "Sum" up to the Hex value of 4F which i believe if i do hex to decimal its 79? So 01 + 53 + 20 + 00 + 41 + 04 (if it was the original values ) then it would be the sum of 4F.. is that phrased a bit better? @cHao

Comment: A bit, yeah.  You're getting into areas where Bash isn't all that great, though.  It really wasn't made for math, and doesn't have much for non-trivial math.  I don't know of any built-in base conversion stuff, for example, so that'd have to be written...and you'd have to take each output char's numeric code and add it to the sum, which means finding ascii codes.  Perl's starting to look more and more attractive.  :P

Comment: Thank you @cHao i will report back with my findings =) BTW, Merry xmas !

Comment: So, i ran into an issue. The response the first time with a specific command came back as a string. but then the next command sent (different one) came back all jumbled up. How can i make sure whatever cat <&3 is outputting gets shown correctly as hex values? @cHao

Comment: You want to see the byte values of what's coming back?  Sounds like a job for `od -x`.  Just pipe cat's output to it.

Comment: thank you @cHao that worked. i was able to use -t x1 as a result the 7th character on to the right = the correct response i needed.